# Modify contents in base class from external class and accessing it from derived class

Tags: java, class, inheritance, null

I have a base class and a derived class and another external class.
I try to update a value in the base class from the external class and 
access it from the derived class.

My class structure is like below:

```
class B:{

bool flag;

setFlag(bool value){
flag = value;
}
printFlag(){
print flag;
}

ExternalClass e = new ExternalClass(this);
}

class External {
B b = null;
External( B b){
this.b = b;
}
b.setFlag(true);

}

Class Derived : extends B{

printFlag();
}
```

Here though i have set the flag to true, the print method prints false.
I dont have a clue as to what is happening . Kindly help me out.

[image: Description Image]

Comment: It would be helpful if you showed you actual code (preferably minimal but compilable). Perhaps you just have a line like `flag = flag;`.

Comment: Posting a [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://www.sscce.org/) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. You don't set any variable to true in your example.

Comment: assylias : I have edited it : Set the flag to true in External Class.

Comment: Is the attribute in the "Base" class supposed to be the same for all instances of "Base" class? You could use the "static" keyword in that case.

Comment: Brainbot : I donot want to use static. Any other class can modify my value of i use static.

Comment: Your code is still not a valid Java program. Show your real code, one that compiles, and it will be much easier to get help.

Comment: I think `C c = new C(this);` and `b.setFlag(true);` must be placed inside respective constructors for this to work as wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some code that does what you wish:

```
class Derived extends B{
    public Derived(){
        super(); 
        // this is the important bit, by calling super() you call the parent classes
        // constructor, which in this case changes the attribute "flag"
        // by using the constructor of the external class on the class
    }
}

class B {
    boolean flag;
    ExternalClass e;

    public B(){
        e = new ExternalClass(this);
    }

    public void setFlag(boolean value) {
        flag = value;
    }

    public void printFlag() {
        System.out.println(flag);
    }

}

class ExternalClass {

    B b = null;

    public ExternalClass(B b) {
        this.b = b;
        b.setFlag (true);
    }
}
```